# Refer to item in enumerate list

Tags: cross-referencing, lists, enumerate

I tried to refer to first and last item of enumerate list without using `\label{}` command in text.

However, it shows the sublist number as well with the item number. Is there any way to fix this so that  it does not show the sublist number "c" in the top line?

"Following list of Question from 1c and 5c has four options"

Following is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xapptocmd{\@item}{\label{cd:\arabic{page}.\arabic{enumi}}}{}{}

\begin{document}
\subsection*{Following list of Question from \ref{cd:\thepage.1} and \ref{cd:\thepage.5} has four options}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item The important issue for test
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item this sublist create problem
        \item do not want ``c'' appearing with 1 or 5
        \item if  last sublist removed, it do not show ``c''
    \end{enumerate}
    \item The next important issue for test by list
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item 15 mm
        \item 20 mm
        \item 25 mm
        \item 32 mm
    \end{enumerate}
\item important issue;
\item another important issue;
\item oh, and yet another critical thing.
    \begin{enumerate}
\item important issue;
\item another important issue;
\item if  last sublist removed, it do not show ``c''
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Already asked for merging these two account.

Comment: I assume you got your code from here: [Automatic labeling of enumeration items](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/174052) (if so, you should link to this question). The problem is that you have not implemented the full answer, and you have duplicate labels. The code in your example only works for 1 level. For others, levels you need to use the slightly more complicated version in the same answer.